# How to perform van Zyl's (2018) ecf-based normality test in R

Tags: r, normality-assumption, characteristic-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have been reading quite a bit on empirical characteristic function (ecf) based normality tests, but cannot find any functions to perform such a test in R and lack the mathematical ability to figure it out myself (The Epps-Pulley test is available in PoweR, but I am looking at one of the modern tests).
I have searched the Internet and emailed journal authors without success.
Would someone be able to help me derive an R function to run the test statistic specified by van Zyl (2018) here https://doi.org/10.1080/03610918.2017.1307397
In this paper the ecf normality test is suggested as $$νn (1) = log(| φ ˆ S (1)/exp(− 1/ 2)|)$$ where $n ( ν n (1)) ∼ N (0,0.0431)$ asymptotically. The Absolute value denotes the modulus
of a complex number if the argument is complex.
Would anyone on StackExchange be willing to assist me with R code for this test statistic?

Comment: Your link is gated. An arxiv version:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06293.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some R code for the ecf (empirical characteristic function) and your test statistic:

```
ecf <- function(t, x) {
    Vectorize( function(t) mean(exp(complex(real=0, imaginary=1)*t*x))  )(t)
}

nu_test <- function(x) log( Mod(ecf(1, scale(x))/exp(-1/2))  ) 

# Some test data
set.seed(7*11*13)
testdat <-rnorm(100)

nu_test(testdat)/0.0431 # =>      -0.08368268
```